# Dot Plots with multiple categories - R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dot

I'm definitely a neophyte to R for visualizing data, so bear with me.

I'm looking to create side-by-side dot plots of seven categorical samples with many gene expression values corresponding with individual gene names. mydata.csv file looks like the following

```
B27      B28      B30      B31 LTNP5.IFN.1 LTNP5.IFN.2 LTNP5.IL2.1
1 13800.91 13800.91 13800.91 13800.91    13800.91    13800.91    13800.91
2  6552.52  5488.25  3611.63  6552.52     6552.52     6552.52     6552.52
3  3381.70  1533.46  1917.30  2005.85     3611.63     4267.62     5488.25
4  2985.37  1188.62  1051.96  1362.32     2717.68     2985.37     5016.01
5  1917.30  2862.19  2625.29  2493.26     2428.45     2717.68     4583.02
6   990.69   777.97  1269.05  1017.26     5488.25     5488.25     4267.62
```

I would like each sample data to be organized in its own dot plot in one graph. Additionally, if I could point out individual data points of interest, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd use `ggplot2`, and facets in particular to make these kinds of plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your [toy] data is stored in a data frame called `a`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
a$trial<-1:dim(a)[1]  # also, nrow(a)
b<-melt(data = a,varnames  = colnames(a)[1:7],id.vars = "trial")
b$variable<-as.factor(b$variable)
ggplot(b,aes(trial,value))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~variable)
```

produces

[image]

What we did:
Loaded required libraries (`reshape2` to convert from wide to long and `ggplot2` to, well, plot); `melt`ed the data into long formmat (more difficult to read, easier to process) and then plotted with `ggplot`.

I introduced `trial` to point to each "run" each variable was measured, and so I plotted `trial` vs `value` at each level of `variable`. The `facet_wrap` part puts each plot into a subplot region determined by `variable`.

Comment: If you want it faceted by `trial` (I called it trial, @Neal calls it `sample`), then the last line of code would be `ggplot(b,aes(variable,value))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~trial)`

Comment: Missed a piece if code. See the edit and give it a try. Let me know if it works

Comment: It seems that because my data set is so big (>15000 rows) that the `a$trial<-1:length(a)` results in `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "trial", value = 1:8) : replacement has 8 rows, data has 15037`. Any thoughts? Thanks for all of your help by the way!

Comment: @Matt, try now. I had an error on my `a$trial` assingment

Comment: If you have more than 15k rows (samples or trials), I **don't** think it's a good idea to facet for trial (`facet_wrap(~trial)`), as there will be just too many facets, they'll render useless.

Comment: To avoid that large x axis, you might even be interested in doing something like this: `ggplot(b,aes(x=as.factor(1),y=value))+geom_point()+geom_jitter()+facet_wrap(~variable)`

Comment: If any of the provided answers actually solved your problem, you may consider marking it as "accepted" with the tick below the answer's voting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use base R, but you need to convert to `matrix` first.

```
dotchart(as.matrix(df))
```

[image: dotchart by gene]

or, we can transpose the matrix to arrange it by sample:

```
dotchart(t(as.matrix(df)))
```

[image: dotchart by sample]