# How to make a grid of dot plots in R

Tags: r, plot, grid, stata

I'm have a sample of data of newborn siblings weight and sex, and want to plot them on a common 2x2 dot plot in R looking like the following done in Stata:
[2x2 plot of birthweight of first compared to second child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9l1h.png)

The stata code is this

```
egen sex1sex2=group(sex1st sex2nd),label
scatter weight2nd weight1st,by(sex1sex2) aspect(1) scheme(s1mono)
```

The structure of the data in R is this:

```
> str(siblings)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ sex1st   : int  1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ sex2nd   : int  1 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ weight1st: int  3740 3060 3650 3688 3740 3550 3850 3680 2390 3600 ...
 $ weight2nd: int  3740 3620 3700 3726 3000 3700 4020 4310 2250 3250 ...
 $ difw     : int  0 560 50 38 -740 150 170 630 -140 -350 ...
```

Only 1:4 needs to be taken into account.
In sex, the 1=boy and 2=girl. In the original .dta file they are labeled.

I have found this thread, which I think is the way to go, but I'm not sure how to wrap my head around it: [Dot Plots with multiple categories - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362838/dot-plots-with-multiple-categories-r)

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: It's not just the Stata name: I think most people would call these scatter plots.

Comment: Hi Nick. I think you're perfectly right. Scatterplots are the more correct term. I'm currently following a course on Biostatistics and the course material is provided i Stata-code, but I've committed to using R, so I sometimes run in to small bumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the thread that you shared, the answer suggests using `ggplot2` to perform the plotting. It's an external package that's super useful for generating (subjectively) more visually appealing plots in R. It's particularly useful for *faceting*, which is what you're trying to do.

First, you'll need to install and load the library.

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
library('ggplot2')
```

I've created some dummy data to illustrate the process:

```
x <- data.frame("sex1" = sample(1:2, 1000, replace = T),
                "sex2" = sample(1:2, 1000, replace = T),
                "weight1" = round(rnorm(1000, mean = 3000, sd = 100)),
                "weight2" = round(rnorm(1000, mean = 3000, sd = 100)))
```

Now we're set to start plotting using `ggplot2`. I'm going to show what *faceting* looks like by first plotting everything without facets. Basically this plots a scatterplot of weight1 (x axis) by weight2 (y axis):

```
p1 <- ggplot(x, aes(x = weight1, y = weight2)) + geom_point()
print(p1)
```

[image]

Right. Now, let's add the two facets you wanted, namely `sex1` and `sex2`:

```
faceted <- p1 + facet_wrap(~sex1 + sex2, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
print(faceted)
```

[image]

While this addresses your issue directly, I'd recommend reading up more on the syntax and applications to understand the functionality of `ggplot`.

Comment: Perfect! That really did it. Thank you so much. I'm still very new to R, so surely I'll go back studying! But thanks a lot!